# passing data from Android Client .net Webservice

Tags: .net, android

I am working on client server for as many as 2 weeks and things are not going that good.
I have a android client and .net web service as my server.

I have to collect the data from the android screens and want to send the data to server which will do my basic CRUD operations.

I had spent some time and managed to send data to server but it is limited for individual parameters like if i wan to send employee name i can send it using ksoap2 envelop and managed to get the data on my server.

but things are NOT FINE when i want to send class object which has employeename,employeeid, etc as its parameters.

I used KVM serializer to create a class employee with the fields above mentioned.

i can only able to retrieve data from server using KVM but not able to send data to server.

I read "Unlocking Android" (good book) book where the author said not to use ksoap if i am not expert in Ksoap. 
Now my question is what i have to use to get this thing working.

Please suggest me quickly so that i can work on it. i have deadline which i have already crossed.

Thanks
Ishwar Naste

Comment: What protocol does the web service use? SOAP? How does it expects the input data to be formatted?

Comment: It is using basic HTTP. When i am collecting data from server the web method will return me class which i collected in SOAP objects

Comment: here is the how i am collecting it. androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();            
            ob = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("RelocationReason");

Comment: PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
     pi1.setName("q");
     pi1.setValue(pc);//This is class objects which has assigned values.
     Request.addProperty(pi1);
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope1 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
     envelope1.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
     envelope1.dotNet = true;
        envelope1.bodyOut = true;
        envelope1.bodyIn = true;
        envelope1.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        XmlSerializer q = null;
  envelope1.writeObjectBody(q, pc);

Comment: when i passed single parameter like employeename i passed it as soap object and it worked fine.. but when i am doing same for passing object reference it is taking null value.. above comment shows how i am passing it now. sorry for not formatting properly..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use JSON serialization. Very simple, straightforward, and android has good support for it.

To debug issues, I would suggest the following:

1. Use a .NET web service client to connect to the service.
2. Use a tool like wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) or fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to view the exact http request being passed to the server from the client.
3. Then capture the http request being sent from your android client and see what the differences are and tweak accordingly.

Good luck.